# How to update dictionary with indexes

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list and dictionary

I need to update my dictionary depend on the list

If dictionary has key existing on list on same name, so then I need to get the index of the list item
and set it as a key of the same dictionary item

```
 list_1 = ['item 0', 'item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4', 'item 5', 'item 6']

 dic_1 = {'item 3': 'val 3', 'item 1': 'val 1', 'item 5': 'val 5'}
```

I tried it with this coding part but couldn't get which I expected result

```
for index, column in enumerate(list_1):
    if column in list(dic_1.keys()):
        print(f"header : {index} - {column} | align : {list(dic_1).index(column)} -  {dic_1[column]}")
        dic_1[column[0]] = dic_1.pop(list(dic_1.keys())[0])
    else:
        pass
```

I expected result:

```
 dic_1 = {3: 'val 3', 1: 'val 1', 5: 'val 5'}
```

Please help me to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't edit a dictionary in that way. Use:

```
new_dic = {list_1.index(x):y for x, y in dic_1.items()}
```

which gives:

```
{3: 'val 3', 1: 'val 1', 5: 'val 5'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this.

```
result = {}
for key,value in dic_1.items():
    if key in list_1:
        result[list_1.index(key)]=value
```